# Помогите достать элемент (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, меню, разметка

Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу достать элемент из многоуровневого списка. Для выделения одной кнопки другим цветом, крашу все в старый синий, а выбранную в тёмный. Проблема в том, что некоторые элементы навигации имеют внутри себя подменю. И их теги "`<a>`" тоже красятся в цвет меню (синий), а они были голубыми.

Кажется, что проблема в массиве. Объясните, что я делаю не так.

Понимаю, что говнокод, но я только учусь. Тег "`<a>`" из меню и подменю желательно не убирать. Подскажите какое-нибудь решение, потому что моя задумка, похоже, неадекватна сама по себе.

```js
//Поменять цвет у выбранной вкладки
function  changeButtonColor(x) {
    
    //получить меню
    var menu=document.getElementsByClassName("vmenu");
    //достать из меню все <a>
    var allBu=menu[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
    
    //перекрасить их всех под цвет меню
    for(i=0; i<allBu.length; i++){
       
        allBu[i].style.backgroundColor="#1378ba";
    }
    //выбранную вкладку покрасить в цвет темнее
    x.style.backgroundColor="#195394";

    //достать <a> в подменю и снова покрасить их в голубой
        var subLists = menu[0].getElementsByTagName("ul");
        var list = [];
        for (i = 0; i < subLists.length; i++) {
            list.push(subLists[i].getElementsByTagName("a"));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i].backgroundColor = "#195394";

        }
}
```

```html
<ul class="vmenu">
  <li id="information"><a onclick="changeButtonColor(this)">Общая информация по API</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="changeButtonColor(this)"><span>Пользователи системы</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
      <li id="login" ><a><span>Авторизация</span></a></li>
      <li id="logout"><a ><span>Выход</span></a></li>
      <li id="logoutGlobal"><a><span>Глобальный выход</span></a></li>
      </ul>  
  </li>
  <li><a onclick="changeButtonColor(this)"><span>Объекты систем</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
      <li id="objects" ><a ><span>Доступные объекты</span></a></li>
      <li id="get"><a><span>Получение информации</span></a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a onclick="changeButtonColor(this)"><span>Модемы системы</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li id="modems" ><a><span>Список модемов</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a onclick="changeButtonColor(this)"><span>Приборы учета</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li id="devices" ><a><span>Список приборов</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName("a")` выбирает **все** элементы `a` внутри текущего элемента, не важно на какой степени вложенности они находятся.

Comment: Понимаю,что в этом и есть проблема. Не знаю как достать уровнем ниже, чтобы перекрыть. Или как получить только элементы первого уровня вложенности. :

Comment: Например получив всех детей с помощью [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) и потом выбрав из них только тех, которые нужны

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас же попробую.

Comment: либо воспользоваться функцией `querySelectorAll`, которая понимает css селекторы

Comment: `function  changeButtonColor(x) {
    var menu=document.getElementsByClassName("vmenu");
    var matches = menu[0].querySelectorAll("li a");
    for(i=0; i<matches.length;i++){
        matches[i].backgroundColor="#1378ba";
    }
    x.style.backgroundColor="#195394";
}`
Я опять что-то делаю не так...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Получаем меню
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("vmenu")[0];
//Получаем все кнопки в меню
var allBu = menu.children;
    
function changeButtonColor() {
   //красим все кнопки в обычный цвет
   for(i=0; i < allBu.length; i++){
      if (allBu[i].tagName == "LI") {
         allBu[i].children[0].style.backgroundColor="#1378ba";
      }
   }
   //красим нажатую кнопку
   this.style.backgroundColor="#195394";
}

for(i=0; i < allBu.length; i++){
   if (allBu[i].tagName == "LI") {
      //красим все кнопки в обычный цвет (опционально)
      allBu[i].children[0].style.backgroundColor="#1378ba";
      //добавляем всем кнопкам действие
      allBu[i].children[0].addEventListener('click', changeButtonColor);
   }
}
```

```html
<ul class="vmenu">
      <li id="information"><a>Общая информация по API</a></li>
      <li><a><span>Пользователи системы</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
          <li id="login" ><a><span>Авторизация</span></a></li>
          <li id="logout"><a ><span>Выход</span></a></li>
          <li id="logoutGlobal"><a><span>Глобальный выход</span></a></li>
          </ul>  
      </li>
      <li><a><span>Объекты систем</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
          <li id="objects" ><a ><span>Доступные объекты</span></a></li>
          <li id="get"><a><span>Получение информации</span></a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><span>Модемы системы</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li id="modems" ><a><span>Список модемов</span></a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><span>Приборы учета</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
              <li id="devices" ><a><span>Список приборов</span></a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ui>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за столь элегантное решение, а то пришлось костылей с двумя классами понаписать.

Comment: @IsinMin, на самом деле плохое решение, и довольно небрежное. Как пример - отсутствие объявления переменной `i`. С классом было бы намного проще.